# Underestimation of peak wavelength by Wien's law for stellar spectra

Tags: temperature, astrophysics, astronomy, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy

I plotted some simulated stellar emission spectrums from PHOENIX which also each came with their respective effective temperatures. With the effective temperatures, I used Wien's law to estimate the peaking wavelength of the spectrums.

[image: The vertical lines are the peak predictions with the corresponding colors for the respective spectrums]

Why does Wien's law seem to underestimate the peak wavelength? Also, why is the error increasing with lower effective temperatures of the star that emits the spectrum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stellar photospheres are not black bodies with a single temperature. The opacity of the plasma varies with wavelength. Where it's more opaque, the radiation comes from shallower, cooler plasma. Where it's more transparent, the radiation comes from deeper, hotter plasma. Thus, the spectrum is a composite of different temperatures. The "effective temperature" isn't defined by the peak wavelength, but by the luminosity/area. Wien's law doesn't apply.

Answer (score 6):

To add to John Doty's answer. The"effective temperature", which *is* the temperature used to identify/define these spectra is given by
$$T_{\rm eff} = \left( \frac{f}{\sigma}\right)^{1/4}\ , $$
where $f$ is the flux per unit area emerging from the photosphere, integrated over all wavelengths, and $\sigma$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant.

As John Doty says, stars do not emit the Planck function; their spectra are complex summations over a continuum of temperatures. At any wavelength, the intensity is approximately that of a blackbody at the temperature where the photosphere becomes optically thin at that wavelength. This temperature is lower, and the spectrum fainter, at wavelengths where we have stronger opacity.

Stars at 5000-7000 K are close to blackbodies because their continuum is defined by the opacity due to H$^-$ ions, which is only weakly wavelength-dependent from the UV into the near infrared. This leads to something that looks a bit like the Planck function, at least between the strong absorption lines caused by atomic transitions.

In cooler stars ($T_{\rm eff}< 4200$ K) the opacity starts to be dominated by molecular species, principally titanium and vanadium oxides and various metal hydrides, with strongly wavelength-dependent opacity. This means there are big changes in the depths from which radiation emerges as a function of wavelength and the spectrum departs significantly from a single temperature Planck function.

Comment: The hottest stars are far from blackbodies due to the "Balmer jump", as seen in the blue curve in the OP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_jump

Comment: Hotter, not hottest - as in a bit hotter than the Sun. You're right, by the time you get to 7500K, the Balmer jump gets important. @JohnDoty